# How do I prove that $\sup|A|=\max(-\inf A,\,\sup A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am given set $A$ which lays in $\mathbb{R}$, and is bounded above and below:

$$  |A|=\{|a|:a\in A\}.  $$

Now I have to prove that 
$$\sup|A|=\max\{-\inf A,\,\sup A\}.$$
However, I have to do that using the following steps:

**1**. Use $|a| = \max\{−a, a\in$ to show that $|a| ≤ \max\{− \inf A,\,\sup A\}$ for all $a \in A.$

**2**. Prove that if $|a| ≤ b$ for all $a ∈ A$, then $\max\{− \inf A,\,\sup A\} \le b.$

I've been struggling with this for a while now. How do I get from the set $A$ to its elements, or well, small $a?$ Isn't it obvious that the absolute value of element $a$ should be larger than $-\inf A ?$ Since it's positive only?

Can someone help me maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Please improve your MathJax to make the question $\sup |A| = \max\{-\inf A, \max A\}$ clearer by using `\max`, `\inf` instead of `max`, `inf`, etc.

Comment: Possibly $\inf A$ is negative and $-\inf A$ is positive, so saying $|a| \ge -\inf A$ is not merely because $|a|$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for $\forall a\in A$,
$$ \inf A\le a\le \sup A\tag{1}$$
and hence
$$ -\sup A\le -a\le -\inf A.\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), one has
$$ |a|\le \max\{-\inf A,\sup A\} $$
and hence
$$ \sup |A|\le \max\{-\inf A,\sup A\}. \tag{*}$$
On the other hand, for $a\in A$,
$$ |a|\le \sup|A|. $$
Since $a\le|a|$ and $-a\le|a|$, one has
$$ a\le \sup|A|, -a\le\sup|A| $$
which implies
$$ \sup A\le\sup|A| \tag{3}$$
and 
$$ \sup(-A)\le\sup|A|. \tag{4} $$
Noting $\sup(-A)=-\inf A$, one has, from (4)
$$ -\inf A\le\sup|A|. \tag{5} $$
$$ a\le\sup |A|. $$
Now (3) and (5) imply
$$ \max\{\sup A, -\inf A\}\le\sup|A|. \tag{**}$$
From (*) and (**), one has
$$ \sup |A|= \max\{-\inf A,\sup A\}. $$